# problem with booting from external hdd

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.02 on an external HDD with 2.0 USB. And I updated it from the system update to get 14.04.

When I turn on the laptop and boot from this HDD I get a purple screen that stays for 3 minutes and then its followed by a black screen with a blinking cursor that will stay for 4-5 minutes and then i get the Ubuntu 14.04 with the 4 dots underneath it and then comes the login screen.

I log in and then a black screen will appear for 5-6 minutes and finally I get to the desktop.

After looking for some solution I read that it could be caused by the VGA drivers. I have an Nvidia VGA. So I got to the "software and updates" and I found the available drivers (all of them are for Nvidia) and downloaded one. Then I booted with `nomodeset` to install the driver.

I hoped that it would solve the problem. But it didn't and now the only difference is that it takes more time to boot and I get to see the Nvidia logo before the login page.

I am wondering if all of this is caused by the fact that I'm booting from an external HDD with USB 2.0, or is there something else, or maybe I missed a step while installing the driver.